# Stop unauthorised file access

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

I am developing a plugin in which is admin only back-end. With a custom role which will be created at a later date, as for now it is just manager.

I am trying to stop the access to everyone getting onto the page, e.g I have the issue where currently if you go to the link, in my case which is `127.0.0.1/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/templates/admin-settings.php` it will show the page but without the css but I believe everything still works.

I've done some research and found the `is_user_logged_in()` function but I don't know if I need to include this in every single file or if there is a global file that I can do this in?

Obviously I know I can do a `require_once auth.php` but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code on top of your file and apply your role condition if required :

`if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly`

For more details follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179773/prevent-direct-access-to-php-files-in-a-wordpress-plugin)  and [other one](https://www.barrykooij.com/prevent-direct-file-access-plugin-files/) !

Hope this will help.

[For more details where to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43212340/what-is-meant-by-if-defined-abspath)

Comment: So, would I have to require `wp-load.php` at the top of the files?

Comment: Read for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43212340/what-is-meant-by-if-defined-abspath and point 2 on this will also help to clear about : https://mikejolley.com/2013/08/13/keeping-your-shit-secure-whilst-developing-for-wordpress/

Comment: please accept answer (tick) if it helped you so that answer can help others as well ! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235